# unable to connect to database from node script and there is no error thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-functions

I have been working with nodejs google cloud functions for a while. I have been facing a weird issue where I can't connect to database servers and there is no error logged not even timeout. I am using node v14.2.0 with pg as postgres library. My nodejs code is

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
let connectionSetting = {
    host: "host",
    user: "user",
    database: "db_name",
    password: "password",
};

const client = new Client(connectionSetting);
console.log(connectionSetting);

client.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`Error connecting to db -> ${err}`);
    }
    console.log("Connection established with PgSql DB ");
});
```

There are no console logs or whatever.
This same code is working on other systems. The database is remote database hosted on gcp and I'm able to connect to it using tablePlus as GUI client.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check the log on the server-side to see if it says anything

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It has to do with the node version. I was using node current 14.2.0 so I installed node lts 12 and then everything works fine.

Thanks for all help